# Deleting my own question on iPhone

Tags: feature-request, ios-app, vote-to-delete

I had posted a question on this site; someone pointed out that there was a valid duplicate, so I tried to delete it on the new iPhone app.

It appears that this is not an option: there is a little clicky-button on the bottom right of the question with the following options:

- Open in Safari
- Favorite
- Share
- Edit
- Flag
- Close

I was able to delete the question on this site - but the option appears to be missing in the app?

I would like to request this as a feature.